# using regular express to find points

Tags: c#, regex

I have six points in a string.

```
1: ([37.788353, -122.387695], [37.829853, -122.294312]) 2: ([37.429615, -122.087631], [37.487391, -122.018967]) 3: ([37.474858, -122.131577], [37.529332, -122.056046]) 4: ([37.532599,-122.218094], [37.615863,-122.097244]) 5: ([37.516262,-122.198181], [37.653383,-122.151489]) 6: ([37.504824,-122.181702], [37.633266,-122.121964])
```

I want to extract them via the regular expression.

```
(\d+:\s([\d+.\d+,\s-*\d+.\d+],\s[\d+.\d+,\s-*\d+.\d+]))
```

But it is not working. Any help would be appreciated. I may use group to place points in a list.

The expected result:

```
[37.788353, -122.387695], [37.829853, -122.294312]
[37.429615, -122.087631], [37.487391, -122.018967]
 ....
```

Comment: In what format are you trying to get the output ?

Comment: Well, you might use [`Regex.Matches(s, @"\[(.*?),\s*(.*?)]")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%28.*%3f%29%2c%5cs*%28.*%3f%29%5d&i=1%3a+%28%5b37.788353%2c+-122.387695%5d%2c+%5b37.829853%2c+-122.294312%5d%29+2%3a+%28%5b37.429615%2c+-122.087631%5d%2c+%5b37.487391%2c+-122.018967%5d%29+3%3a+%28%5b37.474858%2c+-122.131577%5d%2c+%5b37.529332%2c+-122.056046%5d%29+4%3a+%28%5b37.532599%2c-122.218094%5d%2c+%5b37.615863%2c-122.097244%5d%29+5%3a+%28%5b37.516262%2c-122.198181%5d%2c+%5b37.653383%2c-122.151489%5d%29+6%3a+%28%5b37.504824%2c-122.181702%5d%2c+%5b37.633266%2c-122.121964%5d%29).

Comment: Provide an example of the expected output.

Comment: you could use regex, but it totally would make more sense to just parse the JSON and get the values

Comment: `[` and `]` make a character class. http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: in addition to the regex issue, one of the problems is that items 4-6 do not have spaces between the numbers like 1-3 do.  e.g., it says `[number,number]` instead of `[number, number]`.  is your input different like this?

Comment: You provided an expected result as a comma separated list of pairs, but it seems you wanted a different output.

Comment: Yes, sorry about it. I may need an index for the pair. Wrote it in rush,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
\[[\d-.]+[, ]+[\d-.]+\][, ]+\[[\d-.]+[, ]+[\d-.]+\]
```

- `[\d-.]` matches any number and allows a minus sign and a decimal (if present)
- `[, ]` checks for commas and a space between the x and y coordinates

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/obWlll/1)

The output will extract the points the way you want them, e.g `[37.788353, -122.387695], [37.829853, -122.294312]` for the first one and so on.

**NOTE:** If you want to extract the numbers individually as well you could use capturing groups, like this

```
\[([\d-.]+)[, ]+([\d-.]+)\][, ]+\[([\d-.]+)[, ]+([\d-.]+)\]
```

Assuming the points are of the format (x1, y1), (x2, y2) then
- `$1` or the first capturing group will have x1 point (37.788353)
- `$2` or the next group will have y1 (-122.387695)
- `$3` or the next group will have x2 (37.829853)
- `$4` or the next group will have y2 (-122.294312)

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lWbHIy/1) (includes capturing groups)

[C# Sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VsG3uG):

```
var pattern = @"\[([\d-.]+)[, ]+([\d-.]+)\][, ]+\[([\d-.]+)[, ]+([\d-.]+)\]";
var s = "1: ([37.788353, -122.387695], [37.829853, -122.294312]) 2: ([37.429615, -122.087631], [37.487391, -122.018967]) 3: ([37.474858, -122.131577], [37.529332, -122.056046]) 4: ([37.532599,-122.218094], [37.615863,-122.097244]) 5: ([37.516262,-122.198181], [37.653383,-122.151489]) 6: ([37.504824,-122.181702], [37.633266,-122.121964])";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, pattern).Cast<Match>();
foreach (var str in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("x1: {0}, y1: {1}, x2: {2}, y2: {3}", 
            str.Groups[1],str.Groups[2], str.Groups[3], str.Groups[4]));

}
```

Comment: @Bigeyes Take a look at this demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xof2RL. Included the code in the answer

Answer (score 1):

The reason it does not work is that you are not escaping `()`, `[]`. Those have special meaning in regex languages.

Also, there is an error - you don't use * for the space after ',', so only first 3 items would match.

Following fixes those issues:

```
(\d+\:\s\(\[\d+.\d+,\s*-*\d+.\d+\],\s\[\d+.\d+,\s*-*\d+.\d+\]\))
```

Comment: So you mean I have to add escape to `(` or `[`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a simpler regex to extract pairs of values:

```
\[(?<first>[-\d.]+)\s*,\s*(?<second>[-\d.]+)]
```

**Details**:

- `\[` - a `[`
- `(?<first>[-\d.]+)` - Group "first": one or more digits, `-` or `.` chars
- `\s*,\s*` - a comma enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(?<second>[-\d.]+)` - Group "second": one or more digits, `-` or `.` chars
- `]`  - a literal `]`

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/0RMb92):

```
var pat = @"\[(?<first>[-\d.]+)\s*,\s*(?<second>[-\d.]+)]";
var s = "1: ([37.788353, -122.387695], [37.829853, -122.294312]) 2: ([37.429615, -122.087631], [37.487391, -122.018967]) 3: ([37.474858, -122.131577], [37.529332, -122.056046]) 4: ([37.532599,-122.218094], [37.615863,-122.097244]) 5: ([37.516262,-122.198181], [37.653383,-122.151489]) 6: ([37.504824,-122.181702], [37.633266,-122.121964])";
var res = Regex.Matches(s, pat)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => new[] { m.Groups["first"].Value, m.Groups["second"].Value } );
foreach (var str in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}, {1}]", str[0], str[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
[37.788353, -122.387695]
[37.829853, -122.294312]
[37.429615, -122.087631]
[37.487391, -122.018967]
[37.474858, -122.131577]
[37.529332, -122.056046]
[37.532599, -122.218094]
[37.615863, -122.097244]
[37.516262, -122.198181]
[37.653383, -122.151489]
[37.504824, -122.181702]
[37.633266, -122.121964]
```